# Relatively large HDF5 files using h5py - sanity check

Tags: python, hdf5, caffe, h5py, hdf

I'm doing deep learning with caffe and generating my own dataset in HDF5 format. I have 131 976 images all 224x224 which come to about 480MB, and each image has a 1x6 array as a label. I've found that when I generate the .h5 files, they come to 5GB each, 125GB in total. I just want to make sure this is expected. I've checked the contents, but i don't understand how the memory requirement is 250 times bigger. All I'm doing is filling numpy arrays X and Y and creating the datasets (25 in total).

```
with h5py.File('/media/joe/SAMSUNG/GraspingData/HDF5/train'+str(j)+'.h5','w') as H:
    H.create_dataset( 'graspData', data=X)                      # note the name - give to layer
    H.create_dataset( 'graspLabel', data=Y)
```

Comment: What is the shape and type of your data (`X` and `Y`)? And ist this all the code that you have that generates the .h5 file?

Comment: Might just be a problem with your h5py library. I had similar problems using a given h5py library (probably fedora default one), and solved it by switching to anaconda.

Comment: @HannesOvrén X is (53125,3,224,224) per batch (224x224  RGB images). The code before my snippet is just filling an array of the above size.

Comment: What's the type? Because if X is 8 bytes per element then that's almost 60GB. If Y is the same size then you get close to your 125 GB. If it's normal images the type should be `uint8`.

Comment: @JoeWatson images takes only 480MB because they are saved in a compressed format (e.g., jpg/png) while data in HDF5 is uncompressed. the amout of space you need for storing a single image in float32 data type (type accepted by caffe) is 3*224*244*4=~600KB (!)

Comment: To follow up on what @Shai says, while compression is not enabled by default, all you have to do to enable it is to pass the keyword `compression="gzip"` to `H.create_dataset()`. And as @Hannes points out, you may also want `dtype="uint8"`.

Comment: @Yossarian I'm not sure `uint8` is desirable, as caffe expects its input to be in `float32` format.